Prove that $T$ is invertible.
Here is the question that I am thinking about:
Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $A$ is an n-by-n matrix that is the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis of $V.$ Prove that if $$|A_{j,j}| > \sum_{k=1,k \neq j}^{n} |A_{j,k}| $$ for each $j \in \{1, \dots ,n\},$ then $T$ is invertible.
I know the following theorem:
Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $v_1, \dots ,v_n$ is a basis of $V.$ Then each eigenvalue of $T$ is contained in some Gershgorin disk of $T$ with respect to the basis $v_1, \dots, v_n.$
And I know the gershgorin disk definition where $|A_{j,j}|$ is its center and its radius is less than or equal to $\sum_{k=1,k \neq j}^{n} |A_{j,k}|$ and I know that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$ iff $T - \lambda I$ is invertible.
But still I do not know how to solve the question. Could someone clarify to me how to solve it please?

The centre of Gershgorin disk is $A_{j,j}$, not $|A_{j,j}|$.

I am sorry @Pranay

We have $|A_{j,j}| > \sum_{k\ne j} |A_{j,k}|= R_j$, where $R_j$ is the radius of the Gershgorin disk centred at $A_{j,j}$. Then clearly the origin isn't contained in this disk. But any eigenvalue of $T$ is contained in some Gershgorin disk, so no eigenvalue is $0$. Since $\det T$ is the product of eigenvalues of $T$, it is nonzero, which means $T$ is invertible.

is it det T or det $(T - \lambda I)$ that should be product of eigenvalues?

$\det T$ is the product of eigenvalues, as you can show by noticing that (1) the constant term of the characteristic polynomial $\det(T-\lambda I)$ is $\det T$, (2) the product of roots of a monic polynomial is related to the constant term (up to a sign), and (3) the eigenvalues of $T$ are the roots of its characteristic polynomial.
